# How to capture a close event in java swing

Tags: java, swing, windowlistener

I want to capture window close(red X right top position) event. I want to display a specified window upon that window based on the event.

Answer (score 3):

Register a [`WindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) - specifically, use its [`windowClosing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) method:

> Invoked when the user attempts to close the window from the window's
>   system menu.

Answer (score 3):

You need to either implement the `WindowListener` interface, or register a `WindowAdapter`.

Comment: Just to add, this tutorial covers an example of implementing a WindowsListener for Close operation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html