# How to create a handler for window closing in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, window, handler

I'm trying to call a function to do cleanup when my window (created with Java Swing) is closed .
In my initialization code I do this:

```
public class FormLogin extends JFrame{
    private void initComponents(){
        ...
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){
                formLoginWindowClosed(evt);
            }
        });
        ...
    }
}
```

But the function "formLoginWindowClosed" is never called when I press the exit button. I've also tried creating the listener with java.awt.event.WindowAdapter as an argument, but it didn't work either.
How should I create the listener for window closing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture a close event in java swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781108/how-to-capture-a-close-event-in-java-swing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the frame set to exit on close, `windowClosed` will never be called, mostly because the system has already exited before the event can be raised.

Try using `windowClosing` instead.

Alternatively, you could use a [<strike>shut down hook</strike>](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/dwalend/archive/2004/05/shutdown_hooks_2.html)

- [JVM Shutdown Hook in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jvm-shutdown-hook-java/)
- [Design of the Shutdown Hooks API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/hook-design.html)
- [Java Shutdown hook – Runtime.addShutdownHook()](https://www.journaldev.com/9113/java-shutdown-hook-runtime-addshutdownhook)

Comment: Thanks, I changed setDefaultCloseOperation to DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE and now works right.

Comment: @Joel if this solved your problem please think about ticking the empty check mark next to the post. +1 Mad nice stuff

Comment: The shutdown hook link is broken.

Comment: @AdamArold That's the nature of the web - if you're interested, you could easily google "Java shutdown hook"

Comment: I know I can. I just noted that it is broken and as the author of the answer it is your job to fix it.

Comment: I'd be interested in know why this answer might attract a downvote - in what ways does it not answer the OP's question? - In what ways could be improved? Since no new answer has been provided, I can only guess that either you don't understand the question or the answer