# I want my app to do something before it closes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, exit

We put `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` if we want our program to close properly.

What if I want my java program to write something to a file and then close itself.

Which would be the best way to implement it?

Comment: Look into shutdown hooks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720411/how-to-create-a-handler-for-window-closing-in-java-swing

Comment: thanks guys,I got the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `java.awt.event.WindowAdapter` and override this method:

```
windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
```

@AndrewThompson has made a good comment. Furthermore, here I have just assumed a very simple GUI-only scenario. Normally a thread which writes to a file should also care about closing the file channel, best in a finally-clause of a try/catch-block. The whole idea of closing resources in the very last moment is not so good in my opinion.

@Lind In the javadoc of `Runtime.addShutdownHook` you can read:

"Shutdown hooks run at a delicate time in the life cycle of a virtual machine and should therefore be coded defensively. They should, in particular, be written to be thread-safe and to avoid deadlocks insofar as possible. They should also not rely blindly upon services that may have registered their own shutdown hooks and therefore may themselves in the process of shutting down. Attempts to use other thread-based services such as the AWT event-dispatch thread, for example, may lead to deadlocks."

So some care is necessary. If you use parts of your own program or your own file services in shutdownhook, it might not work, but would work in WindowAdapter. If you only rely directly on java.io-package in shutdownhook then this approach will probably work.

In general I repeat and confirm that resources should better not be closed so late. You must have a very good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: Thanks mate,I will use that another time.Shutdownhook seems the way to go for now.

Comment: *"Shutdownhook seems the way to go for now."*  I disagree vehemently.  **This is the best approach.**  A shut-down hook is supposed to run quickly, and if the user has the disks powered down, it might well fail.

Comment: Well,I intend to write and close the file channel with the shutdown hook.@AndrewThompson Does the above method have any other advantages above the idea of using shutdownhooks? .@MenoHochschild The only time when I can close my resources is at the end.

Comment: I appreciate your concern.You both have right answers.I can't select 2 right answers,but I will give you a +1 for showing me a safer alternative and a different approach.

Comment: @Lind `for showing me a safer alternative` so what is you rational for NOT using the safer alternative. The coding effort is the same in both cases. This has multiple up votes compared to the other. I'm curious why you ask for advice but then ignore the advice?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [`Runtime.addShutdownHook`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).
A Shutdown Hook allow you to execute a thread before the VM shuts down.

Here is a small usage example :

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                }
            }
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: 10/10 .Need 7 min to select your answer .

Comment: This is the wrong approach for writing to a `File` (explicitly stated in the question).  Had to add a -1 in case anyone is confused on the matter.

Comment: This was only an example on how to make something happen before the VM shuts down. Instead of printing "Hello", Lind can obviously use the java.io API to open a file, write something in it, then close it proprely. I've done that many times (to remove .lock files in my case), and it works great. So I do not understand your downvote ?

Comment: thats exactly what I intend to do @OlivierCroisier.

Comment: *"I've done that many times (to remove .lock files in my case), and it works great. So I do not understand your downvote ?"*  Do you run you machine in 'energy saver' mode that automatically powers down the disks?  Do you code only for your machine?  Did you read my comment?  I cannot understand what you are confused about.  This is just the wrong way to go, and your code is fragile.

Comment: I don't know what the disk poweroff has to do with the problem at hand. Lind says he HAS to write a file on disk, so doing that from a shutdownhook or from a swing listener is strictly the same from a hardware point of view. Moreover, as you say it yourself, shutdownhooks are fragile only if they use other parts of the program that may already have been shut down. Merely using basic java.io won't cause any trouble. I admit the listener solution may be better because it happens earlier, but the shutdown hook solution, if properly used, it perfectly viable.